# How to change remaining for loops to recursive functions?

Tags: c, function, loops, recursion

Currently what I'm trying to do is convert my remaining for loops into recursive functions. Before, I had a for loop for R1, R2 and R3 which would generate a total payout based on their values.

e.g.

```
1  1  1  payout is 1 

1  1  2  payout is 1 

1  1  3  payout is 1

....... 

3  3  3  payout is 3
```

I was able to convert the first for loop (R1) into a recursive function and my code still compiles just fine. The issue I'm having now is converting the remaining for loops (R2 and R3) into recursive functions as well. I tried copying the format for R1 onto R2 and R3 but I have declaration issues since each variable is in its own function at that point.

What steps should I be taking to approach this correctly?

Here is my current working code with recursive function R1:

```
int totalFunc(int R1, int R2, int R3);

void loopR1(int R1, int upto);

int R2, R3 = 1;
int totalScore = 0;

int main()
{
   loopR1(1, 3);
   return 0;
}

void loopR1(int R1, int upto)
{
   if (R1 <= upto){
      for(R2 = 1;  R2 <= 3; R2++){
         for(R3 = 1; R3 <= 3; R3++){
            printf( " %d   %d   %d  Total Score is:  %d\n\n", R1, R2, R3, totalFunc(R1,R2,R3));
         }
      }

      loopR1(R1+1, upto);
   }
}

int totalFunc(int R1, int R2, int R3)
{
   int totalScore = R1;

   if (R2 < R1){
      totalScore += R2;
      if (R3 < R2){
         totalScore += (2*R3);
      }

      else{

            if (R3 < R1){
            totalScore += R3;
         }
      }
   }

      else{

         if (R3 < R1){
         totalScore += R3;
      }
   }

   return totalScore;
}
```

EDIT:

I added the corrections suggested by R Sahu but the issues I'm having now is R1 isn't incrementing and the program crashes instead of successfully returning 0. I believe the error has to do with section of code I've pasted below.

```
int totalFunc(int R1, int R2, int R3);

void loopR1(int R1, int upto);
void loopR2(int R1, int R2, int upto);

int R3;
int totalScore = 0;

int main()
{
    loopR1(1, 3);
    loopR2(1, 1, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent&format the mess properly!

Comment: I thought I did have it formatted correctly. Do you mean the code formatting or the way its displayed on this website?

Comment: Well, you are right. Just had a look at your local harddisc and it is formatted perfectly. ` else{ if `??

Comment: Is it better now? Still learning how to use this site properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next level recursive function, let's call it `loopR2`, will need to have arguments for `R1`, `R2`, and an `upto`.

```
void loopR2(int R1, int R2, int upto)
{
   if (R2 <= upto){
      for(R3 = 1; R3 <= 3; R3++){
         printf( " %d   %d   %d  Total Score is:  %d\n\n", R1, R2, R3, totalFunc(R1,R2,R3));
      }
      loopR2(R1, R2+1, upto);
   }

}

void loopR1(int R1, int upto)
{
   if (R1 <= upto){
      loopR2(R1, 1, 3);
      loopR1(R1+1, upto);
   }
}
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to implement `loopR3`.

Comment: I added your corrections and believe I'm making the correct changes to the overall code but the issue I'm having now is R1 will not increment over 1 and the program is crashing. The edits I made I posted above, on top of adding the code you suggested above.

Comment: Is there a specific terminology I should look up to continue to study this form of recursion more in detail? I tried to find some more info online to better understand the code but I've had a hard time finding material that closely relates to this form of recursive functions.

Comment: Search for tail recursion.